# Can I use an old internal multicard reader as a USB device?

Tags: usb, card-reader

I got rid of an old computer that had an internal multicard reader (13-in-1, 19-in-1, I'm not sure).  It has a blue rectangular connector with 9 small square holes.  I'd love to adapt this to be able to plug into my new computer, a Dell XPS8930.  It doesn't have any front-facing bay for this, so to use it I'd have to either get an adapter that can make it into USB, or else perhaps drill a small hole and connect it inside.

1. Yes, I know, it may not be worth the effort...and if so, I'm fine with that.  I have one already that I can use but seems silly to waste a good card reader if I can do it easily/cheaply.
2. Assuming it's worth it, what is the best way to go about this?

Thank you for any and all suggestions!

Comment: Depends if it's USB or not. How was it connected before?

Comment: A *rectangular connector with 9 small square holes* is probably a USB2.0 header connector. It's supposed to be connected to the motherboard. Check if yours have it or not. Currently the larger USB3.0 headers are much more frequent.

Comment: Now, a Dell XPS8930 certainly isn't a desktop PC to be adding such accessories. For starters it probably hasn't any USB2.0 header and no way to mount it anywhere in the enclosure (a free frontal optical bay is likely needed and absent in this proprietary design). And such device is redundant because it already has a much newer card reader for all the formats that currently matter.

Comment: As @ChanganAuto suggests, it might be a place to mount a USB connector. See https://electronicsmaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/USB-Type-C-PCB-Design.png , for example, on one PCB layout. If so, you could take the risk of mounting a USB connector and plug an extension into the PC -- **Risk** because if might damage the USB port if it fails.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments thus far.  @ChanganAuto -- you say above that the Dell XPS8930 already HAS "a much newer card reader for all the formats that currently matter."  Am I not seeing that on mine?  I see an SD slot but I shoot CF format on my DSLR and need the larger card reader.  

And yes, you're right, definitely this was originally connected directly to the motherboard.  Ideally I thought maybe there's a little adapter doohickey that I can plug the end of the cable into (the 9 pin rectangle) and the other end is a typical USB.

Comment: https://www.amazon.in/CRJ-9-Pin-Dupont-Header-Single/dp/B07Q4QZW57 But apparently not even the Indian people are interested in this anymore.

Comment: Wow, @TomYan, this is exactly what I was hoping to find.  But alas, unavailable.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Figure out the pinout & just do a hacky DIY job. I did this as a "temporary measure" about 10 years ago & it's still in use ;)

It's soldered & the 2 sheaths cable-tied together to prevent movement, but the "insulation" just all the wires bent out in different directions. It was never meant to be a permanent installation. It's just a regular USB 2 connector on the other end.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a possible solution.  I'm not an engineer but might be able to solder something.  How do I find the pin out diagram or know which wires are the right ones?

Comment: I literally just matched the colours. A 9-pin header is simply 2x USB + 1 signal ground. If you need both channels you need to use 2 old USB cables, one to each half. Mine actually only needed one.

Comment: Thank you again, @Tetsujin -- I'm afraid I don't even know if I'd need "2 old USB cables" or just one.  I want exactly what you have -- a usb connector at the end.  So maybe I'll just cut the wires and see if the colors match?

Comment: I cut open a USB cable and it has 4 wires, a black, red, green, and white.  (Green and white are very thin, black and red are thicker.)  My card reader has five wires:  A thick red and blue, a thin green and white, and a unsheathed wire.  I connected the black-blue, red-red, green-green, and white-white, (didn't solder, just twisted securely), plugged it in and got....nothing.  Not a flicker of life.  Should I try something else?  Or call it a night and admit defeat?

Comment: tbh, unless you can find a published pin-out, you could try some combinations & see if you get one that works.